# Remove Error From Output Using Sed in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm building a list of aws users with this command:

```
aws iam get-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key"
```

If the user doesn't exist you get this output:

```
aws iam get-user --user-name fred --profile=lab 

An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetUser operation: The user with name fred cannot be found.
```

I can suppress that error on the user output with this command, but a new error appears:

```
aws iam get-user --user-name fred --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed 's/^An error occurred (NoSuchEntity)\.*//g' |  jq -r '.User.UserName'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 6
```

I try to remove the parse error with the next line, but it doesn't work

```
aws iam get-user --user-name fred --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed 's/^An error occurred (NoSuchEntity)\.*//g' |  sed 's/parse\ error\.*//g' | jq -r '.User.UserName'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 6
```

How can I get rid of the parse error from the user output?

I'm writing the same line to a log file with the error intact for later analysis. But I don't want the user to see these errors.

Comment: will `set +x; set -x` flags help to understand where error occurs? (after what 1st or second pipe?)
Can you echo intermediate results? (obfuscated if needed)

Comment: what is the purpose of jq here ?

Comment: is this a  `sed` parse error or probably a `jq` (bad JSON input) parse error?

Comment: Why don't you just redirect stderr to `/dev/null` to eliminate all errors?

Comment: Thanks! Sending the errors to /dev/null works. Also the purpose of jq is to print JUST the user name (if he exists). User's may or may not exist in all accounts. And the script scrapes a large number of AWS accounts for info on users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe only pipes the stdout to the next command in pipeline but not the stderr.

You need to discard it

```
aws iam get-user --user-name fred --profile=lab 2>/dev/null
```